# Codable causes loop

Tags: swift, codable

I have these type of classes:

```
import UIKit

class Report: Codable {
    var name: String = ""
    var budgetLines: [ReportLines] = []

    init() {
        self.name = "My Report"
        self.budgetLines = [ReportLines(name: "Test1", parent: self), ReportLines(name: "Test2", parent: self), ReportLines(name: "Test3", parent: self)]
    }
}

class ReportLines: Codable {
    var name: String
    weak var parent: Report?

    init(name: String, parent: Report) {
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
    }
}

let report = Report()
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Report").appendingPathExtension("plist")
let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
let encodedReport = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(report)
try? encodedReport?.write(to: archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)
```

Important detail: the `ReportLines` class contains a pointer to the owning `Report` class. The idea is that one can code something like:

```
myReportLine.parent!.name
```

When I try to save this into a plist, the encoding action hangs. I suspect this is the case, because it tries to encode an object that contains an array of objects that contain a pointer to the outer object. Codable likely goes into a loop.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: You have a circular dependency (parent) - that's why it causes loop. Only manual codable implementation can solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution:

```
import UIKit

class Report: Codable {
    var name: String = ""
    var reportLines: [ReportLine] = []

    enum ReportCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case reportLines
    }

    init() {
        self.name = "My Report"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ReportCodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        reportLines = try values.decode([ReportLine].self, forKey: .reportLines)

        for reportLine in reportLines {
            reportLine.parent = self
        }
    }

    func addReportLine(name: String) {
        reportLines.append(ReportLine(name: name, parent: self))
    }
}

class ReportLine: Codable {
    var name: String
    weak var parent: Report?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }

    init(name: String, parent: Report) {
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
    }
}

let report = Report()
report.addReportLine(name: "Test1")
report.addReportLine(name: "Test2")
report.addReportLine(name: "Test3")

// Saving
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Report").appendingPathExtension("plist")
let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
var encodedReport = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(report)
try? encodedReport?.write(to: archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)

// Retrieving
let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
encodedReport = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL)
let report2 = try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Report.self, from: encodedReport!)

// Comparing
print("\(report.reportLines[2].name ?? "nil")")
print("report!.reportLines[0].parent: \(String(describing: report.reportLines[2].parent?.name ?? "nil"))")
print("\(report2?.reportLines[2].name ?? "nil")")
print("report2!.reportLines[0].parent: \(String(describing: report2?.reportLines[2].parent?.name ?? "nil"))")
```

The only thing I asked myself: Is there a nicer way to call the default decoder instead of providing the init(from:) yourself.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Great idea! Also you can make it shorter by just doing `reportLines.forEach() { $0.parent = self }`